# Load text to custom Listview first, then images one by one

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a custom Listview and Image adapter, along with Universal Image Loader - to load the Image URLs into the List View in an Async task.

The problem is the URLs are dropbox Links and they takes a long time to retreive the shared URL to the image.  If I had 30 images to loop through and get the URL link, it would take a minute to get the actual URLS.

I was hoping it would be possible to modify my code so that:

- Once a single URL is returned, it is passed to the Image Adapter and added to the ListView.

Therefore, the iamges would be loaded one by one, the user would see the images being loaded into the listview and would not have to wait for a long time with nothing happening.

Here is the `doInBackground` as it currently stands:

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {
        //Opens thumbnails for each image contained in the dropbox folder
        try {
            DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];


            for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {
                String filename = fileInfo.path.getName();

                DbxFile file;
                try{
                    if(!fileInfo.isFolder)
                    {

                        paths.add(fileInfo.path); 
                        //takes a long time
                        urls.add(fileSystem.fetchShareLink(fileInfo.path,false).toString());
                        //can we call the imageadapter here somehow to update with this image?
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //must be a folder  so add folder icon
                        urls.add("drawable://" + R.drawable.dbfolder);
                        paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                    }
```

Post Execute simply has:

```
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, urls, paths);
 lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Do I need another Async task for this or what way should I do it?
So one Async take to retreieve the URLs and another async task to load the images?
Can you call one Aync task from another and if so how should it be done?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first fetch all urls from server, or any other data before images.

I would recommend you to use Volley library. On list item inflating,  download images asynchronously.
[Volley framework](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/)

```
YourApp.getInstance().getImageLoader()
                      .get(list.get(position).getImagePath(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.yourImageView, R.drawable.loading, R.drawable.yourDefaultImage));
```

You need to extend your application class with static variables RequestQueue and ImageLoader.

You can find some tutorials on web for sure.